# attribution error when hashing

Tags: python, hash

Hey guys i'm trying to run my program by running the following program...

```
from hashtable import *


def word_count( hTable, filename ):
    """
        Record the frequency of all words in the named file in the hashtable.
        word_count : HashTable String -> HashTable
    """

    # Read the words of the text file into the word count table.
    fd = open( filename )
    for line in fd:
        for word in line.split():
            # using a regular expression argument to strip(),
            # strip out punctuation and convert token to lower-case.
            word = word.strip(",.\"\';:-!?").lower()
            if contains( hTable, word ):
                count = get( hTable, word )
                put( hTable, word, count + 1 )
            else:
                put( hTable, word, 1 )

    fd.close()          # closing the file is a 'good practice'.
    return hTable

def printSummary( theTable ):
    """
    printSummary prints a summary of information about the hash table contents.
    printSummary : HashTable -> NoneType
    """

    # Display the entire table!
    print( "Unique words:", theTable.size )

    # Find the most common word in the text file.
    total = 0
    maxWord = ""
    maxCount = 0
    for key in keys( theTable ):
        thisCount = get( theTable, key )
        total += thisCount
        if thisCount > maxCount:
            maxCount = thisCount
            maxWord = key

    print( "There are " + str( len( keys( theTable ) ) ) + " words." )
    print( "Total words:", total )
    print( '"' + maxWord + "\" appeared ", str( maxCount ),
          " times, more than any other word." )

def printTable( hTable ):
    """
        Print the contents of the given hash table.
        Each key/value pair is displayed in parentheses, tuple-style.
        All pairs appear on a single line.
        printTable : HashTable -> NoneType
    """
    print( "Word Count Data ---------------" )
    lcount = 0
    ltext = 0
    for key in keys( hTable ):
        # print( "(" + key + "," + str( get( hTable, key ) ) + ")", end=" " )
        txt = "(" + key + "," + str( get( hTable, key ) ) + ")"
        ltext += len( txt )
        if ltext > 51:
            print( txt )
            ltext = 0
        else:
            print( txt, end=" " )
    print()

def main():
    capacity = int( input( "Enter capacity (-1 for default): " ) )
    if capacity < 0:
        hTable = HashTable()
    else:
        hTable = HashTable( capacity )
    filename = input( "Enter filename: " )

    wordTable = word_count( hTable, filename )
    printSummary( wordTable )

    while True:

        print( "Commands: k[ey] <word> f[ind] <word> q[uit] ? ", end=" " )
        response = input( ":- " )   # the displayed prompt
        query = response.split()

        if len( response ) == 0 or not response[0] in "fkq": 
            print( response + " invalid. Please enter a command and a word." )
            response = ""
            continue

        if query[0] == "k":
            print( "( " + query[1] + " in text ) is " \
                 + str( contains( wordTable, query[1] ) ) + "." )

        if query[0] == "f":
            if contains( wordTable, query[1] ):
                print( query[1] + " appears " \
                     + str( get( wordTable, query[1] ) ) + " times." )
            else:
                print( query[1] + " in not in the text." )

        if query[0] == "q":
            break
    # 
    answer = input( "Do you want to see the entire table?(y/n) " )
    if answer != "y":
        return
    printTable( wordTable )

# run the main program
main()
```

This program uses...

```
class HashTable( ):
    """
       The HashTable data structure contains a collection of values
       where each value is located by a hashable key.
       No two values may have the same key, but more than one
       key may have the same value.
    """

    __slots__ = ( "table", "size" )


def mkHashTable(capacity=100):
  aHashTable = HashTable()
  aHashTable.table = [[] for _ in range(capacity)]
  aHashTable.size = 0
  return aHashTable

def HashTableToStr(hashtable):
  result = ""
  for i in range( len( hashtable.table ) ):
      if i != None:
          result += str( i ) + ": "
          result += EntryToStr( hashtable.table[i] ) + "\n"
  return result


class _Entry( ):
    """
       A class used to hold key/value pairs.
    """

    __slots__ = ( "key", "value" )


def EntryToStr(entry):
  """
       return the string representation of the entry.
  """
  return "(" + str( entry.key ) + ", " + str( entry.value ) + ")" 

def mkEntry(key, value):
  aEntry = _Entry();
  aEntry.key = key;
  aEntry.value = value;
  return aEntry;


def hash_function( val, n ):
    """
       Compute a hash of the val string that is in [0 ... n).
    """
    hashcode = hash( val ) % n
    # hashcode = 0
    # hashcode = len(val) % n
    return hashcode

def keys( hTable ):
    """
       Return a list of keys in the given hashTable.
    """
    result = []
    for entry in hTable.table:
        if entry != []:
            for item in entry:
                if item.key not in results:
                    result.append( entry.key )
    return result

def contains( hTable, key ):
    """
       Return True iff hTable has an entry with the given key.
    """
    index = hash_function( key, len( hTable.table ) )
    startIndex = index # We must make sure we don't go in circles.
    while hTable.table[ index ] != None and hTable.table[ index ].key != key:
        index = ( index + 1 ) % len( hTable.table )
        if index == startIndex:
            return False
    return hTable.table[ index ] != None

def put( hTable, key, value ):
    """
       Using the given hash table, set the given key to the
       given value. If the key already exists, the given value
       will replace the previous one already in the table.
       If the table is full, an Exception is raised.
    """
    hashCode = hash(key)
    loc = hashCode % len(hTable.table)
    if hTable.table[loc] == []:
        hTable.table[loc] = HashTable._Entry(key, value)
        hTable.size += 1
    else:
        hTable.table[loc].value = value

def get( hTable, key ):
    """
       Return the value associated with the given key in
       the given hash table.
       Precondition: contains(hTable, key)
    """
    hashCode = hash(key)
    loc = hashCode % len(hTable.table)
    for entry in hTable.table[loc]:
        if entry.key == key:
            return entry.value
```

I'm getting the following error...

```
Enter capacity (-1 for default): -1
Enter filename: words.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sps329/Desktop/word_count.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/sps329/Desktop/word_count.py", line 92, in main
    wordTable = word_count( hTable, filename )
  File "/Users/sps329/Desktop/word_count.py", line 29, in word_count
    if contains( hTable, word ):
  File "/Users/sps329/Desktop/hashtable.py", line 83, in contains
    index = hash_function( key, len( hTable.table ) )
AttributeError: table
```

My goal in the program is to implement chaining in the hash program and to come up with a better hash function.

Comment: Can you show the input and expected output? It's pretty hard to figure what are you actually doing.

Comment: Basicall, the program takes in an input file and is supposed to create a hash table for all the words in the file. It eventually prints out the unique words, total # of words, and the contents of the hash table.

Comment: why are you implementing your own hash table?  also consider a `with` block for opening files.  and spaces inside parens/brackets looks weird  :)

Comment: The goal of the project was to alter a open addressing program to make it into a chaining program and create a new hash function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code to construct the `HashTable` instance in `main()` is not correct. You're calling the `HashTable` constructor rather than the `mkHashTable` factory function that actually puts the `table` attribute in the `HashTable` instance. Without the `table` attribute being initialized, you'll get the exception you describe.

Note that that your `hashtable` module has a really crummy design. The `HashTable` class's `__init__` method really should be redesigned to do what `mkHashTable` does. Letting the constructor return a non-functional object is silly.

And its not the only bad design. Almost all of the functions in `hashtable.py` should be methods of the `HashTable` (or `_Entry`) class. Some of them could get special support from Python if they were named in a special way too: `contains` should be a `__contains__` method (letting you test with `word in table`) and `HashTableToStr` should be a `__str__` method (so you could print with `print(table)`).

Comment: I did as you said. I agree with the __init__ and __str__ methods. However, we were told to leave the program as is and alter it in a way to address chaining. I'm now receiving the following error

File "/Users/sps329/Desktop/hashtable.py", line 85, in contains
    while hTable.table[ index ] != None and hTable.table[ index ].key != key:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'key'

Comment: Great detailed answer!

Comment: @user2908101 if your teacher made that code, he really should learn a couple things...

Comment: @user2908101: Ah, it looks like `mkHashTable` needs to be modified to initialize the `table` list to hold `None` values, rather than empty lists. The `contains` function expects `None` or an `_Entry` instance. Speaking of which, you need to use `mkEntry` rather than calling `_Entry(key, value)` in `put`, since there is no `__init__` method in the class.

Comment: I believe chaining requires the mkHashTable to be an empty list rather than a None value. Similarly, would this mean I would need the contains function to expect an empty list?

Comment: @user2908101: Ah, you're right. It's the reverse of what I commented above. You want your code in `contains` to iterate over the values of the list always. If the list is empty, you'll never find your sought item, which is appropriate (it doesn't exist). You need to update the `put` function too, since its the place where values actually get added to the lists. I think with chaining you can skip the `_Entry` objects and just include the values directly.

Comment: @Blckknght hey thanks for all the help. But I'm still confused with the put function and the contains function. I've updated my get function to make loc = hash_function(key, len(hTable.table)). However, i'm stuck when it comes to the other 2 functions.